# how to exclude some file patterns from being processed by rsyslog

Tags: rsyslog

I would like to limit files processed by rsyslog

Currently I have:

```py
input(type="imfile"
      file="/var/log/containers/*.log"
      tag="container-logs")
```

and I need to exclude certain patterns (i.e. not all *.log files should be scraped). For example I want to exclude `*promtail*.log` from being parsed by rsyslog.

#### How to implement?